# Sublime settings exception to file_exclude_patterns

Tags: sublimetext3

Preferences.sublime-settings contains a rule to exclude all files that match '*.json'.  But I'd still like to see some JSON files like bower.json in my folder pane.  Is there a way to accomplish this?  I searched but found nothing.